# Crowdsale over, how to send back token not sold?

Tags: tokens

for my test project we just built up a crowdsale, everything was ok, we tried to send some eth, got some token for it, everything was ok, then we reached the goal, so contributors got paid. But after the crowdsale there was still like 80% of the token on the Crowdsale.

The Crowdsale contract sent back the ethereum to the beneficiary adress, but didnt sent back the tokens, so we just lost the tokens ? Like if it was burnt ?

Isn't  it supposed to send back also unsold tokens ?

Answer (score 1):

No contract returns ethers/tokens automatically, you have to program something in the contract to do it.

It depends on your crowdsale implementation. At the crowsale finalization to return ethers you execute a transfer

```
owner.transfer(this.balance);
```

Assuming the crowdsale contract has ownership of the unassigned tokens you have to execute a transfer to return remaining tokens

```
uint remaining = token.balanceOf(this);
token.transfer(owner, remaining);
```

You can change `owner` for the destination address, and `token` is the crowdsale token.

Comment: So you mean that basicly it always refund token or no ? I'm not sure, coz the first line you say " it returns " and then " you h ave to put this in code " :/

Comment: @LumekaKalume Which contracts are you using? Without knowing your contracts it is impossible to tell. Every contract is different, some contracts have refunding of tokens, others do not.

Comment: I  just took the basic one from the ethereum crowdsale part to be honest, is there any place where i can find prebuilt contract, any library or whatever ? I'm just a webdev, so all of this is a bit new to me. I ty my best, if you just want to tell me where i can get the information and do it by myself i'm ok with. I'm not lazy, just i'm really not confortable wi th it but want to do it as clean as possible :)

Comment: This is the one i'm using https://ethereum.org/crowdsale

Comment: That is a demo of Ethereum capabilities used for learning solidity, I'd not use that contract in production. I'd recommend to try a more complete and battle tested contracts like those of [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity), or [TokenMarket](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico).